# The given value for a taxonomy field was not formatted in the required <int>;#<label>|<guid> format

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, error, taxonomy

I have the following code to set the column default values for a library:-

```
var corpTypetaxValue = listItem["CorpType"] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection;
var corpTypeFieldValueArray = corpTypetaxValue.Select(taxonomyFieldValue => $"1033;#{taxonomyFieldValue.Label}|{taxonomyFieldValue.TermGuid}");
context.ExecuteQuery();
var ttt = String.Join(";", corpTypeFieldValueArray);  
bb.SetFieldDefault(context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(webrelativeurl + "/" + i2["TemplateListUrl"].ToString()+ "/"+mainfoldername.ToString()), "CorpType", String.Join(";", corpTypeFieldValueArray));
```

the above code will work well if the `CorpType` contain single term, but if it contain multiple terms I will get this error when I try to modify the column defaults from the UI:

> The given value for a taxonomy field was not formatted in the required ;#| format.

Comment: How you are adding multiple terms? Can you share the code you are using for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include multiple taxonomy values, the values should be separated by `;#`.

Example:

```
44;#USA|c1815b1d-346f-4ce1-b2cb-15df5e12b0b3;#45;#INDIA|e141d775-7a3b-40aa-a680-98039b375828
```

**Source**:

[Update Managed Metadata column Default Value(s) using CSOM - C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6a25b75c-7886-4117-80f0-97ee23e2a209/update-managed-metadata-column-default-values-using-csom-c)